# Deploying ASP.net Ajax 1.0 and 3.5 web application on same server

Tags: asp.net-ajax

We have a production Server  which has ASP.net 2.0 Application running with Ajax 1.0 and corresponding toolkit (Toolkit version 1.0.20229).

I have been asked to move another application build using ASP.net 3.5 which also utalizes latest ASP.NET AJAX and corresponding toolkit (Toolkit Version 3.0.X).

Can these two application exist on the same server, if I install .Net Framework 3.5 ( current version  on the server is 2.0)?

What all should I do to make sure there is no compatability issues?

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Thank you,

The Mar

RESULT:
Installed Framework 3.5.
 Changes to config file were made according to errors received these include:
removed the folloeing entry:

```
<httpModules> <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/> </httpModules>
```

Had to take out the following section for WCF service in addition to above

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applications should be fine running side-by-side.

If you are distributing the ajax control toolkit as a locally referenced .dll (in other words, you've added the .dll file to your project, and referenced that local file), then you should have no problems with the toolkit.

As for the Ajax (System.Web.Extensions) references, you can do two things:

2) Go through the references in the project and set "SpecificVersion" equal to "true", and that'll force the project to always reference the 2.0 version of it

3) Just use the 3.5 version.  If SpecificVersion isn't set to true, this might happen automatically, but if not, you can map the reference in your first project by using the web.config's [bindingRedirect element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) like so:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding>
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions"
                              publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.61025.0"
                             newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This method is the least invasive, as you don't have to touch the project at all. This will also work for any third party dll's that have explicit references to version 1.0 of System.Web.Extensions.

I've upgraded projects from using the 2.0 framework's version of Ajax to the 3.5 version, and haven't had a single problem.

Good luck!

Comment: @womp- Thank you for your comment. I am going to try  config approach shortly and will be back with reults