# Implications of Conflicting versions of System.Web.Extensions

Tags: asp.net

One of the libraries I am including in my project makes use of System.Web.Extensions 3.5.0.0, which conflicts with my Framework 2.0 application, which uses (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions\v1.0.61025\System.Web.Extensions.dll`).  I can think of 3 possible solutions:

1. Ignore the warning and don't change anything.  I am not sure what the application does to handle this.
2. Add an assembly binding element to my web.config (see below)
3. Configure the application explicitly to use different assemblies (I think this is possible, but don't know how to do it).

However, I am unsure of the implications of each of these decisions.  The application seems to work perfectly fine even when I ignore the warnings (solution 1), but ignoring warnings that I don't fully understand bugs me...as does having warnings like this show up at all.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Edit: I don't think #3 will work, since I'm referencing thinks like the AjaxControlToolKit, which has its own references to `System.Web.Extensions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your application to use specific versions of an assembly by setting "Specific Version" to true in the properties window for the reference.  This stops a global reference from resolving to the latest version of an assembly.

If you're unsure about your global references and what they may resolve to, you can always copy the necessary .dll to a local "Libraries" folder in your application and reference it directly, rather than using a global reference.

You may also find [**this question and answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083203/deploying-asp-net-ajax-1-0-and-3-5-web-application-on-same-server/2083302#2083302) useful.

Comment: When I tried that, it made no difference.  I suspect this is because I'm references the AjaxControlToolkit, which has a reference to System.Web.Extensions, which is not referencing a specific version.